# HttpActionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query returns empty if URL path has %23 (# hash) sign

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, http

I am using MVC4 Web Api Controller and part of my URL contains a %23 ("#").  The client code uses the UrlEncode to make the request.  The service code calls HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpActionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query) to get the query string.  I can get this running correctly on my local environment; however, the version deployed on the server returns back empty string on the HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpActionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query) call.  What do I need to do to make it work on the server?

EDIT: some more info.  Same server code, same URL path but works on local machine but not on the server machine.  For simplicity I use the chrome browser to make the api call.  the URL has been encoded as such http://example.com/api/order/1059%23111?name=xyz%fid=61
This is to get order 1059#111.

When I call localhost:64986/api/order/1059%23111?name=xyz%fid=61, it works, but when I call http://example.com/api/order/1059%23111?name=xyz%fid=61 from the browser, I get an error due to the query string is empty.  On the server in the OnAuthorization call in the class I extend from AuthroizationFilter and I need to parse the query string and I use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query) to get the query name-value pair.  It appears when hitting the server, the actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query returns "" but on my local server it returns "?name=xyz%fid=61".

Below is a code snip in the api

```
    public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return;
        var authHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;

        string qstr = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query);
        NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(qstr);
        if (query.Count > 0)
        {
          ...process validation
        }
        else
          actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized user.");
     }
}
```

If the API call is to my local web api (localhost:64986/api/order/1059%23111?name=xyz%fid=61), then it enters validation if, if call is to the web api on the server (http://example.com/api/order/1059%23111?name=xyz%fid=61), it went into else and returns unauthorized user.  What would cause the different in local vs production server?  IIS or anything need to be added to web.config?

Comment: Your path shouldn't have a hash sign. Anything after the path is going to be treated as a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Comment: @mason: It depends. Fragments are acceptable as part of the URI. They identity that you want a particular portion of a resource returned. It's acceptable in Web Api, so there's some other issue at play here.

Comment: @user1214916: Please expand your question to include specific: exactly what you're trying to achieve, code samples from your project where appropriate, exact error messages you receive, etc. It's kind of impossible to answer your question with just what you've provided.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, but a hash as part of the path isn't good. For example, in `http://example.com/Product/#1BaseballBat/Details?view=personal#Features` anything after the first hash is going to be interpreted as the fragment identifier, even though it was probably intended to only have `#Features` as the fragment identifier. I suspect the same thing is happening here, except the OP didn't show the URL.

Comment: @mason: Oh, yes. Of course. Although, the OP hasn't actually posted an example of what the URL looks like, so who knows what's happening.